# Problem with passing multiple arguments to argparse

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, multiple-file-upload

I am currently trying to automate the process of creating a txt file that will contain the following line: `We attempted to analyze example*.csv files`. The `example*.csv` is user-defined. For this purpose, I am using argparse. I attempted to run the following command `python3 text_gen.py --input example*.csv` but it just throws me an error saying that I am passing multiple files. Also, just to be a bit more clear, I do not want to have the example files to be print as a list but rather look like an input I wrote above.

To make it a bit simpler I am just gonna give an example. In a folder, I have 5 different files example1.csv, example2.csv, example3.csv, example4.csv, example5.csv (the number of files varies each time). I would like to select all of these files and have them so my output looks like the one above: `example*.csv` in my text file.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: the shell is expanding `example*.csv `into the list.  Try quoting it to block the expansion.

Comment: @hpaulj it worked. thanks! I was wondering but is there a way to do it without putting quoting it?

Comment: Escape the star: `example\*.csv`.  Or study the BASH docs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given in the comments by @hpaulj.
To solve the problem above one can either put quotations marks around the input or backslash before *